# How do I find number of vertical lines available in the terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, ansi-term, iterm

I'm writing a script which shows the `git log` for a directory when I `cd` into it.

Such a log can be overwhelming, containing hundreds of lines. So far I have been limiting that to a hard-coded 30 lines with (`... | head -n 30`), cool on the big screen at Work, too big at home. I would prefer the log to take up about half the (vertical) screen on any terminal, e.g. Gnome at work, iTerm2 at home. I do not use screen or tmux. But would like to learn them.

How do I find the number of vertical lines available in a terminal from command line?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Terminal parameters are stored as `$LINES` and `$COLUMNS` variables.

Additionally you can use special term-operation programm, for example `tput`:

```
tput lines  # outputs the number of lines of the present terminal window.
tput cols   # outputs the number of columns of the present terminal window.
```

Comment: `LINES` and `COLUMNS` are only set by some shells. `bash` sets them, *but* only for an interactive shell (and it does not export them).

Comment: The environment vars don't exist in my tcsh.  Also, I wonder if the system would reset them if you resize the terminal window.  Both tput and stty do work for me, so I learned something new :-)

Comment: @jamesqf bash documentation says "Automatically set upon receipt of a SIGWINCH." so, yes, it does change them if you resize the terminal window.

Comment: For autoset above vaiable the following options is responsible `shopt -s checkwinsize` which added in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file with comment: `# check the window size after each command and, if necessary, update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.`

Comment: That command returns a number but I can zoom into the terminal (ctrl - shfit - +) and the number doesn't change. But number of lines visible on the terminal definitely does. I'm using linux mint, xfce, bash.

Comment: @Celada so yes, it also does fire on inititation, oder?

Answer (score 11):

This command should give you the number of lines on the terminal:

```
stty size | cut '-d ' -f1
```

Some systems might not implement `stty size` so you might need something like this instead:

```
stty -a | tr \; \\012 | grep rows | tr -d ' rows'
```

Comment: This seems very OS-specific. Can you compile the list of systems where each incantation works?

Comment: I was afraid that the first one might be OS specific, which is why I added the second one. Indeed after a little bit of Googling I see that the first one probably won't work on Solaris. The second one should be very portable. Honestly, @Costas' `tput lines` seems like the better answer and I have upvoted it. I didn't know about it before.

Comment: I'd like to offer substitute long pipe with `stty -a` by something like `grep -Po 'rows \K[^;]*'` or `sed -n 's/.*rows \([^;]*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: @Costas actually, frustratingly, neither my command nor either one of yours worked on MacOS, so I had to come up with yet a different command (edited). Go figure: MacOS emits "24 rows" instead of "rows 24"! I still think `tput lines` is way better, and I think it's pretty portable!

Comment: Second solution doesn't work on my system. First line gives me a number but I can zoom into the terminal (ctrl - shfit - +) and the number doesn't change. But number of lines visible on the terminal definitely does. I'm using linux mint, xfce, bash.